# Cryptography in NodeJs (SHA-1 ?)

Tags: node.js, cryptography, sha1

I am  learning about `Node js`, I don't know how to use a `Cryptography` libary (SHA-1 ?). How can I use `SHA-1` in `Node js`. Here is pseudo code:

```
// Use a Base64-encoder that don't introduce line-breaks, 
// or trim the output signature afterwards.
string signature = Base64.encode(SHA1.digest(stringToSign));
```

Comment: this might help you.. https://gist.github.com/thinkphp/5110833

Comment: For completeness, note that SHA-1 should no longer be considered secure for cryptographic purposes. Use other hash functions such as the SHA-2 family.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js provides crypto module for you.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
```